# resizeable stacked tabs titles, animated on hover not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs, ellipsis

I am working on resizeable stacked (title dissa...) tabs (similar to chrome tabs) with animated resize on hover to show whole title.

- shrink when they don't have space with `text-overflow: ellipsis;`
- expand when hover
- same width space occupation
- html, css, js (jquery)
- IE8+ compatibility

All is working great in IE8 and Chrome but not in Firefox. Instead of expanding they collapsing.

**updated script:** http://jsfiddle.net/c7kzass6/1/

All ideas or improvements welcomed.

Comment: This question may fit better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, as it is very specific to your situation

Comment: Thanks, I will try. But anyway, this is regular question: How to get something to work or how to write it better.